# Cannot type square brackets in Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my keyboard square brackets are available as an AltGr+F keyboard combination. As Ctrl+Alt+[ is a shortcut in Chrome, I cannot type square brackets in the console window, which are quite common. Is there a solution to this?

My Chrome version is 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

Comment: New stable release is coming https://crbug.com/685993

Comment: Thanks! When will it be available? BTW, it's a Hungarian keyboard.

Comment: As soon as possible. Meanwhile you can install and use a US default keyboard layout or develop in Chrome 59 canary.

Comment: This problem occured to me right now. Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved at version 57.0.2987.110